# Listener to socket at client(Android)

Tags: java, android, networking, sockets

I want to have a listener for a socket at the client side. I am using Android which is Java. I am using TCP/IP but I don't want to loop at the client side.

Is there any method for that or do I have to have my own mechanism for listening?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android being Java, you will have to open a new `Thread` if you want to do asynchronous processing of the incoming data. Be careful to synchronize all communications between the threads properly.

Comment: Hello, could you give me an advice? What should I do in the same situation, but if I want to incapsulate `Socket` work into separate `Thread` and make it as a `Looper`? Should I create two `Runnable`s, one of which will implement a listening and another one will implement a sending, or there is a better way to do that?